# Is there a pretty way to increment an optional Int?

Tags: swift, int, increment, option-type

I want to increment an `Int?` 
Currently I have written this :

```
return index != nil ? index!+1 : nil
```

Is there some prettier way to write this ?

Comment: Nope simple math operators don't work with optionals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, `Optional` has a `map()` method:

```
/// If `self == nil`, returns `nil`.  Otherwise, returns `f(self!)`.
@warn_unused_result
@rethrows public func map<U>(@noescape f: (Wrapped) throws -> U) rethrows -> U?
```

Therefore

```
index != nil ? index! + 1 : nil
```

is equivalent to

```
index.map { $0 + 1 }
```

Comment: I like that the increment is more visible with the `+1` and that it would work with any other number :)

Answer (score 10):

You can call the `advanced(by:)` function using *optional chaining*:

```
return index?.advancedBy(1)
```

**Note:**  This works for any `Int`, not just `1`.

---

If you find yourself doing this many times in your code, you could define your own `+` operator that adds an `Int` to an `Int?`:

```
func +(i: Int?, j: Int) -> Int? {
    return i == nil ? i : i! + j
}
```

Then you could just do:

```
return index + 1
```

Comment: Nice addition to your answer  !

Answer (score 2):

You can optionally call any method on an optional by prepending the call with a question mark, and this works for postfix operators too:

```
return index?++
```

More generally you can also write:

```
index? += 1; return index
```

Comment: As said in an deleted question, this has the downside to not working when index is a constant (let)

Comment: `return index? += 1` doesn't work.  It gives compile error `error: cannot convert return expression of type '()?' to return type 'Int?'`

Comment: You are correct. I have edited my code snippet to fix the problem. Anyway, it still doesn't meet the requirement of working with let and there is already a good answer using map.