# binary operator += cannot be applied to operands of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?' and 'Int'

Tags: ios, swift3, migration

While doing Swift conversion, I got an error:

> binary operator += cannot be applied to operands of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer?' and 'Int'

My code:

```
var avpkt = AVPacket()
var p : UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>? = nil
avpkt.data = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(mutating: inbuf)

p = avpkt.data
p += Int(avpkt.size) // error at this line
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p` is an **optional value**. You should increment it in a safe way.

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33804932/3151675) suggests, you can simply do:

```
p = p.map { $0 + Int(avpkt.size) }
```